# SQL function, that returns values from table by using parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

Need some help with this task:

Parameter type int

If parameter = 0, return all values from table, if parameter > 0, return values, that are bigger than parameter

Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use logic like this:

```
where (@parameter = 0 or value > @parameter)
```